# Tensorflow retrain model performance

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow for poet guide for train own model. I have create retrained_graph.pb and retrained_labels.txt. While I use it in application then I get error that

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Op BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization is not available in GraphDef version 21. It has been removed in version 9. Use tf.nn.batch_normalization(). at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Native Method) at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:118)

After That further train model for application use [Tensorflow for mobile](https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/) blog and create optimized_graph.pb, rounded_graph.pb, mmapped_graph.pb files.

optimized_graph.pb and rounded_graph.pb file work in android application without any error.
While use mmapped_graph.pb I get error that Failed to initialize: java.io.IOException: Not a valid TensorFlow Graph serialization: Invalid GraphDef

Performance of application is not good while use optimized_graph.pb and rounded_graph.pb file.While application camera screen not contain any flower photos otherwise random flower name show with high confidence rate. Any way to detect only flower and remain blank when not flowers.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uYNA.png)

Answer (score 2):

Performance of the application is very good, and is realy fast on the gpu of a mobile phone. The problem is how you build your own model. In fact the tensorflow graph of this application is built to recognize images based on the classes you give to it. In other words if, for example, you teach to the model to recognize 4 different classes of images, it try to label everything it see in this 4 classes. 
For this reason you have wrong results when camera screen don't contain flowers.

A way to "solve" this problem is add an extra class with random images, that probably will have high confidence with no-flowera photos.

If you want a more strict model, you have to use a completely different algorithm.

However keep in mind that which used in the application is probably the state of the art of computer images recognition

Comment: Thanks Davide, Can you provide detail information to which algorithm use to more strict model or any reference for that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any at the moment... However I suggest you to try with a negative sample. I think that it could really give good results.